# Adding YouTube video to cart page magento

Tags: php, magento

```html
   <p>
<?php $attStuff= $_product->getData(); ?>
<?php if( !empty( $attStuff['videoid'] ) ): ?>
<iframe width="330" height="253" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo            $attStuff['videoid']; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<?php endif; ?>
</p>
```

this code working fine for product page but not working for cart page
please cheak this link

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ae4exq0d5

please give me any solution

Answer (score 0):

If you get product from quote item,

```
$_product = $_item->getProduct();
```

You must add to config.xml

```
 <global>    
    <sales>
        <quote>
            <item>
                <product_attributes>
                    <video_id/>
                </product_attributes>
            </item>
        </quote>
    </sales>
</global>
```